# Android Studio Virtual Device Error

Tags: android, virtual, device, android-virtual-device

I just installed Android Studio, but whenever I try to run the emulator it gives me errors like these:

```
C:\Users\Ayusch\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -scale 0.25 -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Ayusch_Phone_API_23
Creating filesystem with parameters:
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

Please Help.
I have already set my `AVD RAM to 512 Mb` , but it still didn't work.

Comment: `emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.`

Have you tried it?

Comment: This is not directly solution to your question, but will solve your request. I do not suggest you to use the Emulator, in stead use Genymotion https://www.genymotion.com is it a virtual solution for mobile development, I used it.

Comment: @TobiaTesan It's the same as disabling `Use Host GPU` in AVD Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable using host GPU unchecking `Use Host GPU` when creating or editing virtual device.

Comment: It worked but the display quality is too poor. Also I cannot move(drag around) the device as the title bar is out of view. At the top. Also it is stuck on the android screen. Device is stuck in a kind of bootloop.

Comment: Try to update graphics driver for your operating system, restart the computer and set maximum resolution. Then try to enable `Use Host GPU` and start emulator.

Comment: I won't be able to upgrade the graphics card. Is there any other way around. My AVD display is also too small.

Comment: I'm talking not about graphics card upgrade but about graphics driver upgrade. Try to edit virtual device and change `Scale` parameter to some bigger value.

Comment: My graphics driver was updated. I edited the AVD but it is still stuck on that android booting animation and not loading the lock screen. Please Help!!

Comment: I think that you have not compatible hardware. It's better to disable `Use Host GPU`. It should not affect display quality of emulator, but it will be slower than using host GPU.

Comment: It is not booting up. Just stuck on the android window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90913/discussion-between-mixel-and-ayusch-jain).